# How to show the arcticle which has more than 3 bids?

Tags: mysql, inner-join, oracle-sqldeveloper, where-clause

[image: The tables I use]

I want to show all `articleName`s that have more than 3 bids. It is also the number of the `Bids` with.

I did it so, but I really don't understand the inner joins. I understand it so that inner join is usefull to connect each table.

```
SELECT ArticleName, bidTime
FROM BID b inner join OFFER o
on b.OID = o.OID;
WHERE (bidTime- auctionEndDate) > 3;
```

Comment: Can you please describe your tables as an SQL statement (DDLs) instead of an image? That would be easier to read.

Comment: You have two statement terminators (semicolons/`;`) in your statement...

Comment: It still dont work. sure i can explain it.

Comment: It should show the article which get more than 3 bids, but i dont understanding how can i show that because that is dont shown.

Answer (score 0):

To understand SQL JOINS please refer to the article bellow:
http://www.sql-join.com/sql-join-types/
It graphically explains joins and this is the basic that everyone should know regarding SQL.

The query for getting offers with 3+ bids

```
SELECT o.articleName
FROM offer o
INNER JOIN bid b on o.oid = b.oid
WHERE b.bidTime < o.auctionEndDate
group by o.oid, o.articleName
having count(b.bid) >= 3;
```

Comment: not a GROUP BY expression. On the line of the select statement

Comment: I edited the answer and added the articleName to the groupBy